# Give an entire Celery chain priority over new tasks

Tags: celery

I want to launch a chain of Celery tasks, and have them all execute before any newly arriving tasks do. I'll have a single worker process handling all tasks.

I guess the easiest thing to do would be to not make them a chain at all, but instead launch a single task that synchronously calls a sequence of functions. But I'd like to take advantage of Celery retries, allowing each task to be retried a different number of times.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single worker running a single process then as far as I can tell from working with celery (this is not explicitly documented) you should get the behavior you want.

If you want to use multiple worker processes then you may need to set [`CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-prefetch-multiplier) to 1.

Comment: Thanks but when I start my chain of tasks and then launch new tasks, the new tasks begin to be executed before the chain finishes.

Comment: what's `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER` set to?

Comment: CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER was 4, but I've now set it to 1 and the problem persists: Start a chain of (task 1, task 2), then start task 3, and the order of execution is task 1 -> task 3 -> task 2.